# Shortest/Cleanest Way to Write This PHP/MYSQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

PHP newbie here; what is the shortest/cleanest way to write the following (counting number of rows in a MYSQL column that match a specific value, and assigning a variable to that total for future use)?

```
$matchquery = ("SELECT * FROM sampletable WHERE Organization_match_participants_contribution = 'Employer Matching contribution' AND " . $where . " = '" . $taxcode . "'");   
$matchresults = mysql_query($matchquery);
$matchrows = mysql_num_rows($matchresults);
```

Comment: Stop using the deprecated mysql_* extension. Migrate to MySQLi or PDO.

Comment: How should one answer this question if you have variables in your query that nobody knows? And as @CharlotteDunois mentioned, using mysql_ is evil!

Comment: And you should'nt concate variable in your query. This can be dangerous things.
Use PDO or MySQLi for security would be cleaner.

Comment: Due to specific limitations, I can only use mysql_* for this project...

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` instead of selecting all columns and then counting it with PHP. `"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sampletable WHERE Organization_match_participants_contribution = 'Employer Matching contribution' AND " . $where . " = '" . $taxcode . "'"`

Comment: @michael what do you mean by saying evil?

Comment: @xatanev, mysql_ is deprecated...

Comment: @grownupteeth I know, but mysql_ isnt evil o>o

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Might be better off using COUNT function in your query:

[w3schools COUNT function basics](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp)